# Update statement fails because I have a column named order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to run an update statement as follows...

```
UPDATE tblDeductionSystem 
   SET [ORDER] = [0RDER] + 6 
 WHERE [ORDER] >= 7 
   AND ScoringCriteriaTypeID = @CheerDeductionScoreSheetID
```

Sql Server if giving me invalid column name ORDER.  I thought if I delimited the reserved word with the square brackets this would work.

Answer (score 4):

If you copied that directly, your error is having a 0 (zero) instead of an O (the letter) on your `[0rder]+6`

Comment: And notice the code colorization of stackoverflow made the color different, a big hint.

Answer (score 1):

What is `[0RDER]`? Is it yet another column? See this zero in there?  `0` vs. `O`. Perhaps you need to change the font of your favorite sql editor.

On a side note, you see it just so happens that 0 and O are close together on QWERTY keyboards and you have to be careful not to hit 0 instead of O. Some [l33t ppl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet_speek) actually prefer 0 to Os.

Comment: Yep... i missed the zero.  Thanks